# Print Java logs in running console (command prompt) and into file while running test through Maven

Tags: java, maven-plugin

I am running a test using maven with below command.

```
 mvn clean test -DsuiteFile=ConfigData/MasterSuite.xml
```

It print java logs in command prompt. But I also wanted to capture same logs into a file. So I added below setting in POM file to achieve that.

```
<redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
```

So now I can capture log but I cannot see running log on command prompt. I wanted to see logs in both command prompt and into a file.

Is there any option to do that?

Comment: you using ubuntu or window ?

Comment: how do you write your logs? you should be able to configure your logging system accordingly

Comment: I am using JAVA logger to capture log.

Logger l
l.info(message);

Comment: Hi @JohnJoe, I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Could someone please suggest?

Comment: I am still looking for this. But didn't succeed yet.